# Вычисление размера mp3 фрейма

Tags: java, mp3

Пытаюсь разобраться в mp3 файлах, почитал вот эту статейку

[MPEG Audio Frame Header](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header#Bitrate)
Затем вытащил из файла заголовок первого фрейма 
из него узнал...

1. MPEG Version 1
2. Layer III
3. Bitrate 320
4. Sampling Rate 44100 Hz
5. Samples Per Frame 1152

   использовал данную формулу.

   > Frame Size = ( (Samples Per Frame / 8 * Bitrate) / Sampling Rate) + Padding Size

   ```
   float fsize = ((1152f / 8.0f * 320f) / 44100f);
   //1.0448979
   //размер должен быть 1044
   ```

В статье написано.

> Because of rounding errors, the official formula to calculate the frame size is a little bit different. According to the ISO standards, you have to calculate the frame size in slots (see 2. MPEG Audio Format), then truncate this number to an integer, and after that multiply it with the slot size

Что нужно сделать, что бы получить корректный результат (как правильно округлить число)

Comment: round(), ceil() пробовали?

Comment: Здравствуйте, мне кажется это не совсем то что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitrate 320 - это 320 кбит/с, т.е.  320 000 бит/с.